# remote git repo digital ocean ubuntu

Tags: git, ubuntu, ssh, digital-ocean

I've recentley signed up for a Digital Ocean account but I'm having trouble setting up a remote repo on there for my projects.

I've setup the SSH key locally and successfully copied these to the server so I can SSH without a password however I'm getting the following error:

```
fatal: '/projects/website/.git' does not appear to be a git repository 
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights 
and the repository exists. 
(32768)
```

This is the address of my remote repo (IP address changed)

```
ssh://root@123.45.678.90/projects/website/.git
```

For the record "/projects/website/" is created in the root folder. I've tried prepending "root" to the address and this didn't resolve the issue.

The remote repo is definitley a git repository and I've tried creating a default repo and pulling, and also a --bare repo and pushing - neither have worked.

I've asked the DO Support team and they are quite slow to respond (probably as we're in 2 different timezones).

I'm now a bit stuck as I'm not sure where the problem lies?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your path is wrong:

```
ssh://root@123.45.678.90/projects/website.git
```

The name of the GIT repository is a name with the extension **.git**.
In your case you should connect over ssh and you should see the file on your webspace.

Comment: Forgot to mention - tried it with and without the slash and I'm getting the same result :(

Comment: Then you should connect to over SSH. And look wheather there is a file website.git in your projects folder. Have you created a bare repository?

Comment: I've tried connecting to a default (git init) repo and a bare (git init --bare) repo, neither have worked.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will want to have

```
ssh://root@123.45.678.90/projects/website/
```

This is due to the fact you want the actual folder that contains your source, not the .git folder within it. This also applies to bare repos, you will simply have an empty folder with only the .git.

Comment: I'm away from my machine at the moment but will give this a try. I've worked with Beanstalk repos before and they always point to the .git folder, but willing to give anything a go. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue. Turns out that your path needs to be the **full path from root**, even though SSH brings you into your user directory.

Log into your digitalocean account via SSH and run command pwd. This will give you the full path probably just /home/username. The line below should probably work for you, unless your username is something other than root. :)

```
ssh://root@123.45.678.90/home/root/projects/website/.git
```

Cheers.